# Event Handling in java mouseListener problem

Tags: java, events

I only want the hover effect on my button which is "hover me" but I do not know why it is implemented on my full frame

Comment: What is exactly not working? Is the button visible but does not display the hover effect? In that case you probably need to force a repaint by calling invalidate and repaint.

Comment: Your `JButton` is as large as the inner area of your entire `JFrame`.

Answer (score 1):

Your `JButton` takes up the entire inner area of your `JFrame`.

I modified your code to put the `JButton` in a `JPanel`, then put the `JPanel` in the `JFrame`.

Here's the revised GUI.

[image]

Here's the revised code.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class HoverEffect extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    JButton b;

    HoverEffect() {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new FlowLayout());
        b = new JButton("hover me");
        b.addMouseListener(new myMouse());
        panel.add(b);
        
        add(panel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        
        setSize(200, 100);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    class myMouse implements MouseListener {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            b.setBackground(Color.GREEN);

        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent e) {
            b.setBackground(Color.white);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new HoverEffect();
    }

}
```